# Attempting to Set Up a Minecraft Server

Tags: minecraft, putty

Does anyone have any experience setting up a Minecraft server with Ubuntu using Putty? To clarify, this server will be running off of a host, not my computer. To accomplish this, I need to install Multicraft, the control panel which I can control my Minecraft servers from. I have been following multiple sets of instructions, but I every time, I follow the instructions perfectly, but I always encounter some sort of problem that prevents me from completing the process.

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www.creativetux.com/2013/03/multicraft-installation-on-ubuntu-1210.html

http://www.multicraft.org/site/page?view=hylianux

Does anyone have more specific instructions that can make this work? Even better, if anyone wouldn't mind walking me though this step by step, add me on skype: TheMattVid.

Comment: You should share more detailed information with us regarding your specific problem! *What* problem in detail do you have? Furthermore you should try to edit your post a bit, multicraft isn't needed for managing a minecraft server, so it should be in your title. --- Edit: Oh try the following: 1. section: what do you use (minecraft, multicraft, which ubuntu..) 2. section: what you are try to achive 3. section: what's going wrong, where in detail do you need the help?

Answer (score 0):

You can start the Minecraft server itself as follows:

Navigate to the folder where minecraft_server.jar is. If you don't have it, you can use the command `wget`:

```
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftDownload/launcher/minecraft_server.jar
```

(Note: I got this link by right-clicking and "copy link location" on the official Minecraft site)

You can then run the server with `java -jar minecraft_server.jar`.

I don't know how to help with any Multicraft-specific stuff, but this should at least get your server up and running.

Comment: My whole purpose of switching from a traditional minecraft host to a vps hosting plan was so that I have more flexible options. For this, I want to run multiple Minecraft servers asa network simultaneously. In order to accomplish this, I need to download a minecraft control panel, multicraft in this situation, which has ftp so that I can upload an already existing server on there and add on to it. I'm hoping to find someone reliable with experience in this area.

Answer (score 0):

The Minecraft wiki has a section about setting up a server on Ubuntu (which I found helpful when I was building mine), as well as a user who has volunteered to field requests for help via email. This person probably knows a lot more about Minecraft server administration than a typical AskUbuntu reader.

- http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server#Ubuntu
- http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Tutorials/Ubuntu_startup_script
- http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/User:Cel1ne